# Why is the set-theoretic principle $\diamondsuit$ called $\diamondsuit$?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, ho.history-overview

A shallow answer would just point to theorem 6.2 in Jensen's 1972 paper "The fine structure of the constructible hierarchy", where Jensen introduces this property.  Or was this symbol used already earlier for the combinatorial principle?

Is there some (deeper) reason explaining how $\diamondsuit$ got its name? Perhaps because $\Box$ was already established as a combinatorial principle?

Comment: I've always assumed it came next after $\clubsuit$

Comment: Because diamonds are rare, precious and strong. Diamonds are forever.

Comment: Asaf Karagila. The phrase "A diamond is forever" is simply a very successful slogan from the diamond industry to make people buy diamonds. Also, diamonds only appear rare because a certain organization has a near monopoly on diamonds and diamond mines and they want us to think they are rare. In reality, they have piles and piles of diamonds.

Comment: @JosephVanName Somewhat interested to know your source of this market-sensitive information.

Comment: Avshalom. My source is Nicky Oppenheimer, the director of DeBeers and richest man in South Africa who made all of his money from diamonds, who said "Diamonds are intrinsically worthless, except for the deep psychological need they fill." The story I gave about diamonds is well known.

Comment: @Joseph: I am fully aware of this. Unfortunately, textual conversation does not always convey humor properly. The correct reply would have been that diamonds can be easily destroyed by adding many reals, so they can't be that precious, strong or forever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Clubbing diamonds" and "Diamond clubs and cartels" sound promising paper titles.

Comment: @Avshalom: That's why I got into set theory. Fertile ground for awesome titles. :-P (Also, I was instantly good at set theory, and rarely good in anything else. But that's besides the point...)

Comment: @JosephVanName Still, one hesitates to bet against a trend, even belatedly: http://www.bain.com/about/press/press-releases/global-diamond-supply-faces-cliff-in-2018.aspx

Comment: @Joseph: By the way, not to belabor the point, but *every* modern currency is intrinsically meaningless and valueless. From gold, to silver, to paper money, to bitcoin and other "Krigerands". They only mean to satisfy some internal value of how much something is contributing to society. Of course, there is severe gamification of these currencies, which is why some things are very expensive and some useful things are cheap. And if you go deeper, then you can observe that *everything* is intrinsically meaningless. But I'm getting into nihilism, and maybe it's a good idea to stop here.

Comment: @JosephVanName Could we agree De Beers and other producers are to certain fashionable metastable allotropes of carbon, as GCH is to $\diamondsuit_\kappa$ for many $\kappa$, there are apparent oligopolies in both fields, and we leave it at that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I once asked Jensen this question, when we were at a conference at Oberwolfach.

I told him that I had always assumed that the diamond $\Diamond$ principle was called $\Diamond$ because it expresses that there is an object exhibiting an elaborate degree of **internal reflection**. After all, if $\langle A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ is a $\Diamond$-sequence, then it very often happens for $\alpha<\beta$ that $A_\beta\cap\alpha=A_\alpha$, which is an instance of $A_\beta$ reflecting to $A_\alpha$.

But alas, this was not his reason. The actual reason was less interesting, having mainly to do, he said, with him simply needing a new symbol that had not yet been used, and that one was available.

Meanwhile, I believe that we should all adopt my explanation anyway! Henceforth, let it be known that a $\Diamond$ sequence is one exhibiting beautifully captivating **internal reflections**!

Comment: I don't know. I like the original explanation. It's like the origin of the Ctrl-Alt-Delete combination. They just needed a way to reboot the system quickly, and that was an unused combination.

Comment: Just to amplify "available": Anyone who printed work in logic would have the diamond and square symbols available, because of their use in modal logic. Jensen probably expected that his use of these symbols for combinatorial principles would never clash with their use for modal operators. That was too optimistic; I once wrote a paper in which both uses of square occur.  But I"m not aware of any clash involving diamond.

Comment: In the modal logic of forcing, the assertion $\Diamond\Diamond$ is a theorem of ZFC, where the first diamond means "forceable" and the second is the combinatorial principle. Meanwhile, $\neg\Diamond\square\Diamond$ is also provable, which is to say that the combinatorial principle is not possibly necessary.

Comment: That internal reflection principle sounds attractive but it is too weak. Is it possible to view a diamond sequence as some stronger sort of internal reflection principle? My formulations couldn't get past CH.

Comment: Nevermind, it's hopeless as diamond is $\Sigma^2_2$.

Comment: The use in modal logic was as early as 1932 when Lewis and Langford introduced $\diamondsuit$ in the book $\textit{Symbolic Logic}$.

Comment: @Andreas: So you had a proof there you had $\square\square\square$, where the first one is a modal statement, the second is a combinatorial property, and the third one means "QED"? :-)

Comment: @Ashutosh One bit exceeding CH to give $\diamondsuit$ is $\clubsuit$, but it seems to reflect only in conjunction with CH.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fortunately, it wasn't quite that bad. The combinatorial square came with a cardinal as a subscript, and The two squares were never in the same formula.  (The paper is "Infinitary combinatorics and modal logic" JSL 55 (1990) 761-778.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins So $\curlyvee$ and $\curlywedge$ stand for upward and downward reflection?

Comment: @Goldstern I don't understand your remark. Could you clarify?

Comment: They look like the two halves of a cut diamond (to me).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Just a stupid joke.  The two halves of the diamond look like two-dimensional corner reflectors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_reflector), so one  reflects downwards, the other upwards.

Comment: Ah, I see. That would have an affinity with Solovay's set-theoretic modality:  $\diamondsuit\varphi$ means that $\varphi$ holds in some $V_\kappa$ with $\kappa$ inaccessible.